# How to enabled/disabled angular-material datepicker from the controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

How can I enabled/disabled angular-material datepicker from the controller I know that you can disabled the datepicker like this `<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" disabled></md-datepicker>`, if I do that the datepicker appears disabled and that's good but I need to be able to enable it again after the user press a select option, I try using `ng-disable` like this

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Delivery date:</label>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
                                           md-max-date="maxDate"
                                           md-min-date="minDate"
                                           md-date-filter="myFilter"
                                           ng-disabled="enabledDisableDate">
     </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

but it didn't work.

The only way that I managed to disable the datepicker was like this

```
`<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" disabled></md-datepicker>`
```

but I need to be able to enable it again from the controller after the user press a select option from a select.

**EDIT** 
I tried  `ng-disabled` directive  like I showed at the begin of the question

in my controller

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();    
$scope.enabledDisabledFunction = function (id)
{
   $scope.enabledDisableDate = false;
}
```

but it didn't work.

I think that it's because I initialize the datepicker in my controller like this `$scope.myDate = new Date();` after calling the function, but I not sure if this could be the problem

Comment: Look at my updated answer, I have added the working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-disabled directive. [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Works great for me, please provide your code, maybe you mistyped something.

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding: 40px;" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled" /> Disabled
  </label>
  <hr />
  <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-disabled="disabled"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question, but still it doesn't work it doesn't disable the datepicker

Comment: I have changed my answer, does it work for you? Because it is working fine for me.

Comment: yes now it's working my problem as that I wasn't initializing the disabled variable in my controller I put this at the begging of my controller and now it's working `$scope.disabled = true;`

Comment: Glad you have found the reason. Did you down vote my answer (why?) and then accepted it? :)

Comment: @Antipod I'm not sure he can down vote it, given he has less than 150 rep. Unless users can on their own questions.

Comment: no friend I didn't downvoted your question, but I can upvoted it if you want or is that against the rules?